# Buildingflavours when creating own nginx-core .deb file

Tags: nginx, make

I have to create a .deb file from nginx source which include some additional modules.

I downloaded the src files and edited `debian/rules`.  For the `core` flavour I added my modules and compiling works.

Then I removed the other flavours because I only need the `core` one.

Then compiling fails because a obj file fromg `nginx-full` can't be copied.

`cp: cannot stat ‘debian/tmp/debian/build-full/objs/nginx’: No such file or directory`

Why do I have to compile `nginx-full` when I just want `nginx-core`?

Comment: Hve you removed them from debian/control?

Comment: Ok removed them form `debian/control` and it looks good. Is this the only/recommended way to do this? Feels kinda weird to delete half of the file to achieve this.

Comment: I don't know other way not to build all packages mentioned in control file